# Why is Android GUI building so Frustrating? What am I missing?

Tags: android, user-interface, intellij-idea

I am trying to construct a GUI for my class Android Project. I am currently using IntelliJ IDEA 12 with the Drag-And-Drop GUI Builder. I know enough about going in the text and editing attributes as well.

The problem I have, is that I can't seem to simply..make the GUI for my application the way I want it. In normal Java I'd be able to do it very fast with Swing. But since Android doesn't have anything Swing, it's tricky to say the least.

I would think that I could simply make it, using LinearLayout nesting. But that just turns out wrong all the time.

Below is a quick image I made in Netbeans of how I want the GUI to look like:

[image]

I simply cannot obtain this easily in IntelliJ. If I place a Button in a Horizontal Oriented LinearLayout it fits in fine. But if I then add an ImageView, the layout already screws up there! And then I place a button on the other side of the ImageView which didn't help anything either.

Am I missing something here, or is Android GUI's simply this frustrating?
Can I (Like in Swing) code the GUI entirely in Java? Or am I forced to use XML?

Comment: I really think you should rethink the question's title.

Comment: It's frustrating because you don't know what you're doing yet. Yes, you can code it completely in Java-but honestly, I wouldn't. Personally I find it easier than Swing, but YMMV.

Comment: Have you tried using a RelativeLayout? Also, yeah, I wouldn't code it in Java. You think the XML is bad?

Comment: You are missing the Android Development Tools http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: @gpasci No I downloaded the Android Manager and got the 4.2 Android Source. That ADT bundle is for Eclipse which I quite frankly despise at the moment.

Comment: @Catherine Yes I have tried using a RelativeLayout, but when I go into Landscape mode the application just..looks ugly. Because nothing is relative any more but hardcoded sizes. Yeah XML gets tedious I feel. I have no visual feedback on what I am doing before I switch between views. Quite annoying to work with.

Comment: @Vipar two thoughts: 1) usually you would design a different layout for Landscape mode if you're not happy with the automatically done translation of your Portrait layout (and most of the time you won't be). 2) I'm sorry you despise Eclipse ;) but it would solve the "no visual feedback" issue since the ADT does have a way of not only seeing your layout in realtime but also designing it completely visually.

Comment: @Vipar It's a matter of taste and available time, the layout you are trying to build can be created with a couple of clicks and drag and drops in Eclipse. You should really consider it.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions. There is a vast Internet out there, beyond StackOverflow, where you can post rants. The only actual questions here appropriate for StackOverflow are in the last 18 words ("Can I (Like in Swing) code the GUI entirely in Java? Or am I forced to use XML?"). The answers are "yes, you can use Java, though few developers need to" and "no, though that's what most developers do", respectively.

Comment: @Catherine You can design it completely visually in IntelliJ as well. But writing XML code needs a "Refresh" of the Visual side every time you make a change. I am kind of shooting in the dark when I write the XML because in my mind I have an expectation of what will come of this but about 95 % of the time, it comes out entirely different, and I have to sit and go back and forth against and again trying to fix it. Also, I feel the Eclipse IDE is simply too cramped up, slow and generally not very intuitive.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks and I know this. This is not a rant. This is a question asked about the programming of GUIs in Android, since maybe I was just overlooking something. Apparently I must be, because it doesn't seem to matter which IDE I use. The GUI building is just clumsy.

Comment: You might consider editing your question to make its nature as a question more clear. Questions have specific actionable items, describe precisely what the differences between expectations and reality are, and so on.

Comment: I totally understand your frustration as someone who has struggled with both Swing and Android GUIs. I would suggest experimenting with the Idea visual designer a little until things start to click for you. I was exactly where you are only about a month ago. If you're interested I've made an intro to Idea screencast that walks through a basic GUI here: http://bit.ly/Zu6q8i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't perfect, you'll need to work with it, such as sizes and positioning, but basically is what you want. Took maybe 5 minutes, maybe less in Eclipse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.00"
        android:ems="10" />
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well I didn't expect full code, but thanks for the effort. What I don't understand is, that none of it is really aligned at all. Is this normal, and is just something you have to fiddle with?

Comment: That's what I said you'd need to work on

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I will try look into that.